# Purge records from netezza tables

Tags: netezza

Delete record older than 20 days from Netezza tables.
Procedure will take table_name and timestamp as an input. 
Does any one know  procedure for this?

Answer (score 1):

A procedure can be written but it should be noted that Netezza is a DW solution and works well with large data, Your system performance can be hit painfully by delete method instead 
One option i can suggest is create another temp table with the data you need to retain and drop older data table after processing rename temp table with old table name if you need same table name due to some reason.

Steps for my suggestion -

```
step 1 => Create table <temp_tbl_name> as select <fields> from <tbl_name> where <timestamp_field> > 20 days
step 2 => drop table <tbl_name>
step 3 => alter <temp_tbl_name> to <tbl_name>
```

Race condition -

> For above solution before following the steps you need to acquire lock on the table

You can write following steps in shell/Java/ or DB procedure as your wish and comfort level.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Groom table  is the command for it

Comment: Please provide a code example and a link to the documentation of the commane (if possible).

Comment: Groom does not purge records older than a certain date. Groom will remove *deleted* records from a table (and by default, only if those records have been captured in a backup).

Answer (score 0):

Couple options based on the final goal:

- You can flag with a logical delete(e.g., ACTV_ROW = 0)

  UPDATE
  SET
  ACTV_ROW = 0
  WHERE ROW_DATE < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 20)
- You could DELETE based on a WHERE clause, this would logically delete within the netezza system though, records are not completely gone until the table is groomed

[useful link on deletes](http://nztips.com/2012/07/how-to-undo-a-delete-in-netezza/)